# Conditional return type with template

Tags: c++, templates, conditional-statements

I want to use a conditional return type related to a template in C++.
C++ 11, 14 and *17 preview* are available on my environment.

I am not new to programming, but I am new to C++ and a bit confused with some functionalities.

What I want to achieve is :

If template is `int32_t` my return type will be `int64_t`, `int16_t` will return an `int32_t` and `int8_t` will return an `int16_t`.

Actually I am using a generic template for both :

```
template <class T, class T2>
static T2 Foo(T bar1, T bar2) { //do something }

int64_t x = Foo<uint32_t, uint64_t>(555555, 666666);
```

I would like to make this a little more practical by having to type only the parameters type.

```
int64_t x = Foo<uint32_t>(555555, 666666);
int32_t x = Foo<uint16_t>(12000, 13000;
int16_t x = Foo<uint8_t>(88, 99);
```

I tried to implement it with `std::conditional`:

```
template<typename OtherType,
        typename T = typename std::conditional<(sizeof(Type) <=   
        sizeof(OtherType)),
        OtherType, Type>::type>
```

I am open to use overloads and crazy ideas.

Comment: Why would you use templates for this? Just overload

Comment: @MooingDuck I suspect he doesn't want to repeat the same body for all the overloadings. Otherwise it doesn't make sense to use templates actually.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An idiomatic way to do that in C++ is using traits.
As an example:

```
template<typename> struct foo_ret;
template<> struct foo_ret<uint32_t> { using type = uint64_t; };
template<> struct foo_ret<uint16_t> { using type = uint32_t; };
// And so on...
```

A template parameter for the return type is even no longer required now:

```
template <class T>
static typename foo_ret<T>::type Foo(T bar1, T bar2) {};
```

And you can invoke it as it follows, as requested:

```
int64_t x = Foo<uint32_t>(555555, 666666);
```

Or let the compiler deduce `T` if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks you very much, I was searching  a way to do this exactly for a long time now. You just simplified 20% of the code in my current project :)

Comment: @Lizi You are welcome. Traits are widely used. It's just a matter of being confident with them. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

you could try a compile time map to get the return type you desire

```
typedef boost::mpl::map<
    boost::mpl::pair<uint32_t,uint64_t>,
    boost::mpl::pair<uint16_t,uint32_t>,
    boost::mpl::pair<uint8_t,uint16_t>
> type_map_t;

template <typename T>
typename boost::mpl::at<type_map_t,T>::type Foo(T bar1, T bar2) {}
```

Comment: This answer work as well, but is dependent to boost. Thanks for the share, it is always good to have some alternatives :)